# How do I find the distance traveled by an object during a specified second given a condition?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, kinematics

The problem is as follows:

> An object starts moving from rest and accelerates. On which second the
>   distance traveled by such object will be equal to the triple of the
>   distance traveled by that object on the fifth second?

The alternatives given on my book are:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{12 th}\\
2.&\textrm{11 th}\\
3.&\textrm{13 th}\\
4.&\textrm{15 th}\\
5.&\textrm{14 th}
\end{array}$

Okay what I attemped to do in this problem was to refer to the equation for accelerated motion as shown below:

$x(t)=x_{o}+v_{0x}t+\frac{1}{2}at^2$

As it mentions that starts from rest then the initial condition would be $v_{ox}=0$ ;
Now the second part I'm assuming that starts from $x_{o}=0$ which in other words would be right from the start of the reference point.

This would make the equation like this:

$x(t)=\frac{1}{2}at^2$

Since it mentions the distance traveled to the $5^{\textrm{th}}$ this would be plugin that number in the above equation to find the distance traveled to that point.

$x(5)=\frac{1}{2}a\left(5\right)^2=\frac{25}{2}a$

Because it mentions what second would the distance be triple of that I assumed equating the first equation with an unknown time to three times the third equation would render the result.

$\frac{3\times 25}{2}a = \frac{1}{2}at^2$

Therefore:

$3 \times 25 = t^2$

$t= 5 \sqrt 3$

But oddly this doesn't appears within the alternatives. For this part I'm confused. What exactly did I mistakenly understood?

Can somebody help me with the procedure I took?. I revised the way how I did the steps algebraically and it looks okay, but I'm still confused if what I attempted to do was not right?. Can somebody guide me in the right path?.

Comment: Distance traveled 'on' fifth second apparently means distance traveled *during* the fifth second, which is given by $x(5)-x(4)$, that is by subtracting distance covered in $4$ seconds from distance covered in $5$ seconds. So you need to solve for $t$:$$x(t)-x(t-1)=3(x(5)-x(4))$$

Comment: @ShubhamJohri But If I follow that route still it doesn't produce a result within the alternatives as I'm left with $\sqrt{27}$.

Comment: Distance travelled during $t^{th}$ second $=x(t)-x(t-1)=\frac a2[t^2-(t-1)^2]=\frac{27}2a$ giving $t=14$.

Answer (score 1):

As [Shubham Johri](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/551962/shubham-johri)'s comment indicates, the question says traveled *on* the fifth second, i..e, between the fourth & fifth seconds. Thus, the distance traveled it's referring to is $x(5) - x(4) = \left(\frac{25}{2}\right)a - \left(\frac{16}{2}\right)a = \left(\frac{9}{2}\right)a$. Similarly, the question asks for the value of $t$ such that $x(t) - x(t-1) = \left(\frac{t^2}{2}\right)a - \left(\frac{(t-1)^2}{2}\right)a = 3\left(x(5) - x(4)\right) = 3\left(\left(\frac{9}{2}\right)a\right) = \left(\frac{27}{2}\right)a$.

Do you think you can finish the rest?

Comment: I attempted to follow the route that you mentioned however it doesn't yield a result within the alternatives given. Because if you equate $\left(\frac{27}{2}\right)a=\frac{1}{2}at^{2}$, Therefore $t=\sqrt{27}$, then  $t=3\sqrt{3}$. Did you obtained a result other than that?. Or perhaps did I misunderstood something?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell Note the second part of the last set of equations is not $\frac{1}{2}at^2$, but it's $\frac{1}{2}at^2 - \frac{1}{2}a(t-1)^2 = \frac{1}{2}a(t^2 - (t^2 - 2t + 1)) = \frac{1}{2}a(2t - 1)$. Equating this to $\frac{1}{2}a(27)$ gives $2t - 1 = 27 \implies 2t = 28 \implies t = 14$. This is the provided option #$5$.